# Accessing outer template class typedefs from inner template class specialization

Tags: c++, namespaces, inner-classes, class-template

Consider the following code

```
template<int>
struct outer{
    typedef int outertype;
    template<int=0, int=0> struct inner;
};

template<int o> template<int,int> struct outer<o>::inner{
    void f(outertype){}
};
template<int o> template<int i> struct outer<o>::inner<0,i>{
    //void f(outertype){}   //test.cpp:11:9: error: ‘outertype’ has not been declared
    void f(outer<o>::outertype){}   //ok but more verbose
};
```

I highly suspect that the error in the comments is a g++ bug (4.8.2), or is it a strange subtlety in the name lookup rules?

Comment: That is strange for me is that the verbose version seems to not require `typename`.

Comment: @Jarod42 why would it? afaik `typename` is required where there's an ambiguity on a value or type identifier, here I can see none.

Comment: if you use `outer<i>::outertype` instead, it requires `typename`...